# I have an existing site that I need to add to github. What is the best way to add lots of files to a github repository?

Tags: git, github

I need to take a lot of file from an existing website and put them into a git repository. What is the best way to add these files into an existing git repository from my ftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to locally save all the files you want to use from the FTP server, into a `new_project` directory. Then:

- [Create a new repository in GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/) called for example, `new_project`. Assuming the clone URL of the project is: https://github.com/user/new_project.git
- Execute the following commands in your Terminal:

  ```
  cd new_project
  git init
  git remote add origin https://github.com/user/new_project.git
  ```

[Add the files](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-from-the-command-line/) in the repository.

- Stage the file for the first commit to your repository:

  ```
  git add .
  ```
- Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository:

  ```
  git ci -m "Initial commit"
  ```
- [Push the changes](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/) in your local repository to GitHub.

  ```
  git push origin master
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm saving the files locally but it is taking forever. It's been over and hour and over 40,000 files. Is this normal?

Comment: It depends on how big your files are, the FTP server upload bandwidth, and your download connection speed...